# Rendering Json arry in Django Template

Tags: json, django, django-templates

For reducing the number of table  I put the values of table as json string and stored it in a text field my problem I override the admin view of the specific model with now I have to render the the text field with json data in well defined tabular format

This is the value of the json string I have to render in the change_form.html that I  already overrided 
    [{'name': 'name', 'value': 'dfgdgd', 'label': 'Name used Account', 'type': 'text'}, {'name': 'email', 'value': 'dfgdfgdfg@ghng.gh', 'label': 'Account Email Address', 'type': 'text'}, {'name': 'url', 'value': 'sdfsdfsdf', 'label': 'Web Address (URL)' , 'type': 'text'}]

Comment: could you post the codes so that people can help you.

Comment: Use json.loads to convert the json string into dict, then pass it to template.

Comment: What you have posted is not valid json.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the json back into an object, and pass that object to the template:

```
import json

def my_view(request):
    s = "[{'name': 'name', 'value': 'dfgdgd', 'label': 'Name used Account', 'type': 'text'}, {'name': 'email', 'value': 'dfgdfgdfg@ghng.gh', 'label': 'Account Email Address', 'type': 'text'}, {'name': 'url', 'value': 'sdfsdfsdf', 'label': 'Web Address (URL)' , 'type': 'text'}]"
    s = s.replace("'",'"') # json must be double quoted
    o = json.loads(s)
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'data': o})
```

Then in your template:

```
{% for obj in data %}
    {{ obj.name }} - {{ obj.value }} - {{ obj.label }} - {{ obj.type }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I have to pass the the json  into admin view  how solve that?  if its for  html form in the front end method above will work fine will work ?

Comment: That's not what you asked in your original question. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I override the admin view of the specific  model with now I have to  render the the text field with json data in well defined tabular format .

Comment: This is an entirely different thing than what you asked. I suggest you delete this question, and ask another question with the exact problem you are trying to solve.